# tinyMCE in upgraded moodle 4.2.1 not working

Tags: tinymce, moodle

After a server upgrade to moodle 4.2.1 tinyMCE editor stopped working: the toolbar is empty.
Nginx raises errors like:

```
Primary script unknown while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.62.175.236, server: ############, request: "GET /########/lib/editor/tiny/styles.php/1699796159/tinymce.js"
```

the editor was uninstalled and then reinstalled but the issue remains

Comment: 1. Can you switch on debug to see if there are any PHP errors - https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Debugging#Enabling_debugging 2. If you are upgrading, can you try upgrading to 4.2.3?

Comment: Thanks: with debugging the error are Deprecation's cases: "Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property theme_config::$removedprimarynavitems is deprecated in /var/www/liceomaffei.it/html/m/lib/outputlib.php on line 800 Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property additionalregions::$regions is deprecated in /var/www/liceomaffei.it/html/m/theme/learnr/layout/includes/blockregions.php on line 50 Invalid get_string() identifier: 'pluginname' or component 'local_bulkenrol'. Perhaps you are missing $string['pluginname'] = ''; in /lang/en/local_bulkenrol.php? line 355"

Comment: I add that 1) JS caching is disabled, 2) in the pages where tinymce is supposed to work (where text areas are present): the browser console shows some errors: the most relevant one is this, IMO: "loader.js:60 
 GET https://######/lib/editor/tiny/loader.php/-1/tinymce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)" (while indeed tinymce is in /lib/editor/tiny/js/tinymce/tinymce.js with correct permissions and ownership)

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, looks like you have some plugins that need upgrading too

https://moodle.org/plugins/theme_learnr

https://moodle.org/plugins/local_bulkenrol

I would recommend checking to see if any contributed plugins need upgrading, they might be contributing to TinyMCE not working correctly

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Upgrading#Check_for_plugin_updates

Also upgrade to the latest version of 4.2.x which is currently 4.2.3

Comment: Thanks. Apparently they're all up to date